# Launch Browser Home Page or Bookmark When Screen Turns On

Tags: android, google-tv

I'm looking to run a slideshow from a web page on an Android Google TV. I want the browser to launch and point to a bookmark every time the TV turns on. Since this is a Google TV there are no worries about the lock screen or what not.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up a service that listens to Action.BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast. In that service, launch an intent to view the bookmarked page.

The code snippet here might help you get started:

http://www.androidsnippets.com/autostart-an-application-at-bootup

Comment: Does the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast occur every time the TV turns on from sleep mode or only when it turns on after being powered off (with the power removed)?